# javascript. animation logic on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have this blocks of content that i want to show and hide on hover with an animation.

First i have e default content-element. That one gonna be diplayed if no element in the list is hovered. when an element int he list gets hovered i want to look up the corresponding content-element and show that.

I made a jsfiddle that shows my problem. It would be great if you can help me do this with animations. thanks!

Anyone that can provide some help here?

```
jsfiddle.net/xf1b0g9a/2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with some builtin methods like `.fadeIn(), .slideDown()` etc.

```js
$(function() {
  //hover
  $('a').on('mouseover', switchContent);
  $('ul').on('mouseout', function(){ 
     $(".content").hide();
     $('.content.default').show();
  });

  function switchContent(event) {
    var id = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content#" + id).fadeIn(); // use fadeIn() to see a fade effect.
  }

});
```

```css
ul{border:solid 1px red;}
.content{display:none;}
.content.default{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a data-id="1" href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a data-id="2" href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a data-id="3" href="#">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content default">
  <h4>default.(show if no element is hovered, hide if other element is hovered)</h4>

  <p>default text</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="1">
  <h4>1</h4>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="2">
  <h4>2</h4>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="3">
  <h4>3</h4>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

<sub>*: *I have changed the markup little bit.*</sub>

Comment: thanks! hmm, default content should show up if 1,2,3 is not hovered tho.

Comment: then in this case you have to bind an `mouseout/mouseleave` event on the `ul`.

Comment: Thanks! how would it look if you instead made the show/hide with classes? so you can do some css transitions instead.

Comment: like so the new element animates in and the last one animates out when switching.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `display` attribute, use the `visibility` attribute and set `opacity` to 0. Then use the `animate` function of jquery to set `opacity` to `1`:

```
$(".content#"+id).animate({'opacity' : 1});
```